# Writing a regexp redirect if url match pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create a 301 redirect rule for a website I'm setting up. The old link structure is as follows:

http://www.domainname.com/projecttype/subtype/post-name

The new structure is:

http://www.domainname.com/projectname/projecttype/subtype/post-name

So basically I need to add "projectname" between domainname and projecttype. But only if there is a subfolder after projecttype. As domainname.com/projecttype/ <-- need no redirect..only redirect if a subdirectory after this exist in the url.

I've never written any regexp or redirect rules before..tried searching for something that matched my need without any luck so far :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/projecttype/(.+)$ /projectname/projecttype/$1
```

That's assuming that both project type and name are static.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Will give it a go. Just a short follow up question:  wouldn't the domain be needed before "/projecttype/" to avoid a loop ? I mean since /projecttype/ would still exist in the url after the redirect..only now with /projectname/ before it? Or does the "^" before /projecttype/  handle this in some way? :)

Comment: @user3708279 it won't loop because the regex matches URI's that *start with* `/projecttype/` (that's what the `^` does), so when you redirect to `/projectname/projecttype`, that won't match the regex.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks alot :)